# dell poweredge 2800 - Raid 1 disks offline

Tags: windows

I have 4 disks in the raid with scsi, however, they went offline, the 3 have orangish color and the 1 has green. When I go into the perc bios, I can change the status to online but not sure how to save that setting and overall to get the server back online.

Please help
Morris

Answer (score 0):

(This is not really an answer, but the comments section is too small.) You are not providing a clear explanation of the problem.

- RAID 1 is a mirror and can only have two drives. Is it RAID 0+1?
- It is highly abnormal to have so many drives failed all at once. It suggests some other problem such as incorrect SCSI termination, a loose SCSI cable connection to the backplane or controller, or an electronics failure of the SCSI backplane board. You provide very little background detail so there is no way to tell.
- Simply changing the drive status back to Online is not the complete answer. Server drives don't just go offline suddenly for no reason. The *Set back to Online* controller option is generally for **last-resort emergency purposes only**. It is there just to try to help in recovering data from drives that known to be failing, before removing the dying drives, and then discarding and replacing them. The only exception is if the fault is really found to be somewhere else, in the cabling, termination, or backplane.
- This server was first sold in 2004 so hard drive reliability after 15 years is highly questionable. I used an old PowerEdge 2800 for years, but ran it as 4-drive RAID 5 with two hotspare drives (6 drives total) because I don't trust them.

You are likely going to have to replace the 3 drives marked bad, or the SCSI hotplug backplane board. Partial to total loss of data looks to be highly likely.